# Proof of the prime number theorem

Tags: number-theory, analysis, analytic-number-theory

I read this proof of the prime number theorem:

PRIME NUMBER THEOREM: 
$ψ\left(x\right)-x=O\left(xe^{-c\sqrt{\log \left(x\right)}}\right)$ for some effective $c\in\mathbb{R}_{+}$

PROOF: 
$ψ\left(x\right)-x=O\left(∑_{_{|γ|\leq T}}|\frac{x^{\rho}}{\rho}|+\frac{x}{T}\log ^2\left(x\right)\right)$ (where the sum is taken over the non trivial zeros $\rho+iγ$ of the $\zeta$ function with multiplicity what i know as explicit Riemann formula). 
Than one has $∑_{_{|γ|\leq T}}|\frac{x^{\rho}}{\rho}|=O\left(x^{1-\frac{c}{\sqrt {\log \left(x\right)}}}\log ^2\left(T\right)\right)$ (I can give more datail if needed but the idea is using the zero free region to estimete $x^{\rho}$ and the Riemann Von Mngoldt formula for $∑\frac{1}{\rho}$). 
So by substituting $T=e^{\sqrt {\log \left(x\right)}}$ one get the result.

MY OPINION 
With this substitution i get $ψ\left(x\right)-x=O\left(x\log \left(x\right)e^{-c\sqrt{\log \left(x\right)}}\right)$ someone can help me to find the mistake please? Do i miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

$x\log(x)e^{-c\sqrt{\log(x)}})
=xe^{\log\log(x)-c\sqrt{\log(x)}})
$
and since $\dfrac{\log\log(x)}{\sqrt{\log(x)}}
\to 0$,

$\begin{array}\\
\log\log(x)-c\sqrt{\log(x)}
&=-c\sqrt{\log(x)}(1-\frac{\log\log(x)}{\sqrt{\log(x)}})\\
&\lt -c_1\sqrt{\log(x)}\\
\end{array}
$

for a different $c_1$.